# How to calculate the CPU load when viewing video (web-server on linux)

Tags: linux, web-services, video, load, video-streaming

I have a shop of video courses. How to calculate the CPU load when viewing video (web-server on linux)?

Comment: have you tried the `top` command?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a kernel-internal value, so you won't have to *compute* anything, you just will query the kernel for that value.

Interactively you can use the `top` command, as Daniel stated in his comment.

Programmatically, `top` will be cumbersome.   Instead, you can use `uptime` as a high level tool for this.  Use `uptime | { IFS=\ , read a b c d e f g h i j k l m; echo "$j"; }` to only get the current load.

A little more lower level would be to use the proc file system.  The file `/proc/loadavg` provides the information about the load.  You can use `cut -d' ' -f 1 /proc/loadavg` to only get the current load.

For the smoothed-out average values of the load (there typically are given three values, the first is the current load, the two others are averages over long time periods), use `$k` or `$l` instead of `$j` in the `uptime` solution, and use `-f 2` or `-f 3` in the proc file system solution.